# Is it possible to record the audio output of a pc directly on a usb device?

Tags: transfer, transmitter

Lets say we have a wav file - 96000 hz sample rate. And lets say we play this file.
Is it possible to find something like an external soundcard/ specialized usb dongle that could automatically record the file being played and save it to an sd card? Without quality loss?
What im really interested in is not converting the digital file to analogue. And sadly im limited to usb...
And no, it cant be transmitted via copy pasting on a stick.

Edit: I can't access usb mass storage devices because of the security measures present on the pc. Basically I need to get a certain digital sound out of the pc in question "as is", without any sort of quality loss. For pen testing purposes.
While hdmi could work, usb would be preferable.

Comment: What prevents you from simply copying the file? You don't have direct access to the file but you do have direct access to the audio as it's played back? I feel there's a part of your description missing, or you're trying to find a method to a solution you've decided on, without actually telling us the full problem, which makes it feel a bit like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: Good point. Editing the question.

Comment: The PC in question has no network access either? No CD writer?

Comment: nope. im working on a doctorate thesis on communiction between air gapped devices. basically i need to use an usb port to get a sound out of a pc. "pixel" perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. It's unfortunately not straight-forward, nor will it be cheap, but it is do-able - except not via USB.

I can give you one example of having done this myself, but you're not going to like the answer - becuase it's particularly pricey - but remember, this is just one example.

Sound Devices 970, MADI/DANTE recorder. 
RME MadiFACE in the computer, connected via MADI to the SD 970.

Simply select the MadiFACE as your output soundcard and then press record on the SD970.

Other options are to use a DANTE recorder such as the SD970 and use a simple DANTE interface directly from the computer. DANTE Virtual soundcard would work fine as you can select this as your default output device.

So basically, any DANTE recording device would work fine.

If you are dead set on USB, then the best solution is to find a cheapo USB sound card with a TOSlink or RCA SPDI/F output and then select a recording device that has a TOSLINK or RCA SPDI/F digital input and that records onto SD card.

Marantz Professional PMD561 has a digital input if you can still find one, as does the Tascam DR-100MKIII

Comment: Thanks. Im off to google all the things you just said. :)) A long journey ahead of me.